# How to match a string after colon on Regex

Tags: python, regex

```
text = Bounding box for object 1 "PASpersonWalking" (Xmin, Ymin) - (Xmax, Ymax) : (160, 182) - (302,431)
```

I need only : `(160, 182) - (302,431)` from the text

Comment: In python you could use `r'(?<=: ).+'` -- But depending on the characters after the end of your string this may need to be modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
rgx = r'^.+:(.+)$'
re.search(rgx, text).group(1)
```

`^`: Start at beginning of string

`.+:`: Allow any characters until a colon

`(.+)$`: Capture all characters until the end of the string

To put it in the format x,x,x,x:

```
>>> rgx = r'^.+: \((.+),\s*(.+)\).+\((.+),\s*(.+)\)$'
>>> m = re.search(rgx, text)
>>> result = f'{m.group(1)},{m.group(2)},{m.group(3)},{m.group(4)}'
>>> result
'160,182,302,431'
>>>
```

Comment: sir, is there  any way to find 160,182,302,431 from that text on these format